# Why is XGBoost saying my dataset is empty despite having data in it?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, xgboost

Not sure why XGBoost said the dataset is empty.
I have enclosed the codes below

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder

X, y = diamonds.drop("cut", axis=1), diamonds[['cut']]

# Encode y to numeric
y_encoded = OrdinalEncoder().fit_transform(y)

# Extract text features
cats = X.select_dtypes(exclude=np.number).columns.tolist()

# Convert to pd.Categorical
for col in cats:
   X[col] = X[col].astype('category')

# Split the data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y_encoded, random_state=1, stratify=y_encoded)]


# Create classification matrices
dtrain_clf = xgb.DMatrix(X_train, y_train, enable_categorical=True)
dtest_clf = xgb.DMatrix(X_test, y_test, enable_categorical=True)


params = {"objective": "multi:softprob", "tree_method": "hist", "num_class": 5}
n = 1000

results = xgb.cv(
  params, dtrain_clf,
  num_boost_round=n,
  nfold=5,
  metrics=["mlogloss", "auc", "merror"],
)
```

Results of output:

```
[13:51:04] WARNING: ../src/metric/auc.cc:328: Dataset is empty, or contains only positive or negative samples.
[13:51:04] WARNING: ../src/metric/auc.cc:328: Dataset is empty, or contains only positive or negative samples.
[13:51:04] WARNING: ../src/metric/auc.cc:328: Dataset is empty, or contains only positive or negative samples.
[13:51:04] WARNING: ../src/metric/auc.cc:328: Dataset is empty, or contains only positive or negative samples.
```

expect to run rmse after the model

Comment: Did you try "print"ing the X-train and y_train for example?

Comment: Please read errors correctly, it says: "Dataset is empty, or contains only positive or negative samples", so the dataset could be empty OR have only samples of one class (your data should have at least two classes).